# how can i convert a png to pdf using JavaScript in vue.js with node version 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have tried using jspdf but it works with node version >=12. so i used only canvas instead. here when i do canvas.toBuffer, it says it is not a function.

so far my code is:

```
const canvas = createCanvas(2480, 3508, "pdf");
          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          loadImage(`URLTOImage`).then(image => {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 2480, 3508);
            const buffer = canvas.toBuffer("application/pdf");
          })
```

Comment: You can't convert to a pdf using canvas. It's not an image type, it's a binary filetype. You'll have to use a serverside library, like the one you linked, or create your own if you need to use node 10. Can you not spin up a more modern version of node in a docker container, and use that for your converter?

Comment: Or use https://github.com/alvarcarto/url-to-pdf-api

Comment: @Jack_Hu, Thanks for the suggestion but no due to limited resources i have to keep using node 10. do you know any other way? i just have the png image in a url and i  have to convert it into a pdf using vue.js

Comment: You can't do this with VueJS, or any other client-side JavaScript, nor should you. This question is nothing to do with JavaScript, nor with the web really. You want a file format converter, plain and simple, which is always going to have to take place on a server, **not in a browser**! @IVOGELOV has provided the kind of thing I was thinking of. Grab a free-tier compute instance or microservice instance of GCP or AWS, and chuck the above link on to it, open the ports, and get converting with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

luckily i got the solution by myself. i used pdfmake dependency to make it work, here goes the code:

```
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake'
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

docDefinition() {
      return {
        content: [
          {
            image: 'base64code of Image'
            width: 550,
            height: 820,
          },
        ],
        pageSize: 'A4',
        pageOrientation: 'portrait'
      }
    },
    async makePDFFun() {
      this.generatePDF = await debounce(() => {
        pdfMake.createPdf(this.docDefinition()).getDataUrl(dataUrl => {
          this.pdfDataUrl = dataUrl
          saveAs(this.pdfDataUrl)
        })
      }, 0)
      const rar = await this.generatePDF() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Plain and simple.

You're attempting to convert binary filetypes, which can't realistically be achieved in the browser, and for good reason.

This is a server-side operation, and therefore needs to be performed on a server in some way-shape-or-form.

@IVOGELOV has already provided a solution for you, which is available on github for free:

https://github.com/alvarcarto/url-to-pdf-api

There's even a button at the very top of the README, that takes you directly to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/home) to deploy it.

Just click the link in the following image:

[image: Heroku deploy]

You can get it up and running in minutes, for free.